# Why didn't flagging comments affect my Flagging Summary or Flag Weight

Tags: support, flag-weight, comment-flags

Yesterday I flagged a number of comments. In fact I used up my allotted number of comment flags. Some of the comments were immediately deleted which if I understand correctly means the comment had accumulated enough flags to be deleted without moderator interaction.

Based on my reading of [What is Flag weight?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight) I expected some change in both my flag weight or my flag summary yet even after roughly 24 hours nothing changed.

Did I do something wrong? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: they don't seem to show up in your flag history either.. maybe something to do with how insignificant comments are?

Comment: comment flags don't add to your flag weight anymore. Here's an upvote though, for all your missed flagweight. Given how worthless flagweight really is, I bet it's a good deal :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comment flags do not affect flag weight. I don't know if this was ever officially announced, but it has been the case for several weeks at least.

Comment: That's too bad. Perhaps someone should update the bit in Tim Stone's [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight/80178#80178) where it says "your flag weight increases by 10 points for flags on posts, and **5 points for flags on comments**."

Comment: @Conrad: updated. (you could always do that yourself, too...)

Comment: Is this true also for the "other" flag on comments? That one involves typing some text, which has to be reviewed my moderators, so I'd expect _this_ type of flag to affect flag weight. (The other flags work without moderator intervention, so I found it natural that flag weight isn't affected.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Not sure if we tested that too. I'll make a junk comment here which you can flag. Ping me when you've done it, since comment flags don't appear in the header.

Comment: @mmyers: Thanks! I'll watch my flag weight.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Looks like it had no effect.

Comment: @mmyers: No, it hadn't. Thanks for the experiment! (Generally speaking I find the outcome somewhat unfortunate, but personally I don't care about my flag weight.)

Comment: @mmyers: Sorry, just another quick question. When I flag a comment as "obsolete" (or any other of the text-less radio buttons), will moderators (and 10k users?) see that flag and act upon it?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Moderators will see it, but I don't think 10k users do anymore.

Comment: @mmyers: Ah, thanks, that's good to know. So if a glaringly obsolete comment is on a post with recent activity, it might be deleted by sufficient community flags; but in any case, a mod can speed up the deletion - great.