# Do comment flags accumulate flag weight?

Tags: support, comments, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why didn't flagging comments affect my Flagging Summary or Flag Weight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100033/why-didnt-flagging-comments-affect-my-flagging-summary-or-flag-weight)

It seems to. People every where state that the flag weight increased with every successful comment flag. Why then, when I flag comments, don't they appear in my flag history. And also, when the comments get deleted, why don't I get an increase in flagweight?

Comment: Actually, scratch that. It seems they do not increase flag weight any more (see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100033/why-didnt-flagging-comments-affect-my-flagging-summary-or-flag-weight/100034#100034)

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think that they do accumulate flag weight.

However, this is easily tested when you find the next inappropriate comment.

Comment: From the question that tombull89 posted above, it seems that comment flags do actually accumulate flag weight.

Comment: @Thursagen See tombull's addendum.  They did, but they do not add to your flag weight any longer.

Comment: That, is just sad.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Well, I just tested to determine (it was easy to find a comment to flag) but it has obviously been confirmed in the meantime; no worries, but remember that this is probably (supposedly) the least significant number related to your profile.