# Does flagging site proposals count towards flag weight?

Tags: discussion, area-51, flags

A while ago, I found the ["FuN"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37540/fun) proposal on Area-51 and flagged it, adding a note that (IMO) it was not a real proposal. Sure enough, the proposal was closed as "Not a real proposal" shortly afterwards, so apparently other people flagged it too.

Yesterday, I flagged another proposal as a possible duplicate.

I cannot see my flag weight on Area-51, nor do I have a "Citizen Patrol" badge there. So I am led to believe that flagging proposals (as opposed to flagging example questions) on Area-51 doesn't count towards flag weight.

This is fine with me, but it makes me wonder - is there a rationale behind this?

Comment: AFAIK, flagging comments, chat messages and A51 proposals do not result in an increase of flag weight. I need to find a source, though.

Comment: @tombull89 FWIW it seems that comment flags [don't contribute to flag weight](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100034/168333) in any SE site. Note, however, that the poster there didn't find an official source, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Area 51 does not have flag weight.  It was forked long before flag weight existed, and there hasn't been a compelling reason to add it to Area 51 since the flag volume is so low.

Answer (score 0):

Flag weight can only be seen on your Area 51 meta profile. Flagging proposals will not contribute to your visible flag weight. That's not to say flag weight on the main site is not counted.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? Also, you _can_ get the [Citizen Patrol](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/8/citizen-patrol) badge on Area-51 main.